# UIButton text appear for sometime and it shows emptytext for anothersometime in ios?

Tags: ios, uibutton, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I am new in iOS development. I want to show `UIButton` text for 1 second, and show no text for another 1 second. Can any one tell me the logic in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Using  `NSTimer` with regular `TimeInterval` of 1.0, change the text of `UIButton`

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your .m file

```
- (void) changeNameOfTheButton{
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeNameOfTheButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        [button setTitle:@"Title 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

and then in your **viewDidLoad** call the above method like this :

```
[self changeNameOfTheButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
[button setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormalState];
```

and for empty:

```
[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormalState];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `NSTimer` for setting the time interval to change the title.

Add the following line in `viewDidLoad`

```
 [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(ChangeButtonText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Function  which is called when timer triggers. Here change the button title.
 Copy this method to your `.m` file.

```
  -(void)ChangeButtonText
  {
   if([_button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"buttonName"])
    {
        [_button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormalState];

     }
   else
    {
       [_button setTitle:@"buttonName" forState:UIControlStateNormalState];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(btnPress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


-(void)btnPress
{
    if([btn.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Hello"])
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
        [btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(animateButton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)animateButton
{
    if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""])
        [button setTitle:@"your text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```